# NSBox background color

Tags: cocoa, nscolor, nsbox

Is there a system-defined NSColor for the background of an NSBox? Testing shows it to be RGB (226, 226, 226) but there does not seem to be anything like `controlBackgroundColor` for it to easily switch when in Dark Mode. I am using this color for the background of a custom NSView and don't really want to embed the view in an NSBox to get the effect I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [AppKit Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_mojave_10_14_release_notes/appkit_release_notes_for_macos_10_14), the fillColor of a *custom* NSBox is set to **controlBackgroundColor**, **windowBackgroundColor**, or **underPageBackgroundColor**, but those aren't the same as the background for a *default* NSBox.

I asked this same question earlier in Apple's Developer Forums (also looking to provide a dark mode color), and aside from the usual boilerplate responses, the answer was that there is no system color name for it.  The standard control and gray colors are a bit darker, so if you want to match the default you will need to roll your own.